# Where can I get aosp marshmallow rom (device:merlin) ? Will I have to build it from scratch?

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom

I want to port miui using aosp as base rom . I searched on the web but didn't find any aosp rom for my device.I owns a Moto g turbo(merlin).So will I have to make it from scratch from the instructions provided  on aosp site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I could search quickly, I found there's Lineage OS Port for merlin. You could use that as base for porting MIUI without porting or building AOSP.
 [Here's the device tree of it](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_motorola_merlin)

First try to find a similar device to turbo having MIUI port. If you could find that, it would be easier to port from that device relatively.

Comment: There is a miui rom available for moto x play  and Xiaomi Mi4i both having Snapdragon 615 as same as  g turbo.The problem with Moto x play's miui is that it is of Brazil region and MI4i has miui Based on lollipop but i want to port for Marshmallow.

Comment: Will using Lineage os be a good idea as it has a bad battery backup(I tried it) , will it affect the going to be ported rom's battery backup too?

Comment: For porting Marshmallow based MIUI, you'll need marshmallow as a base so try to find similar & while it is generally true that if your base ROM has some problem, ported ROM based on it will have the similar problems, But you may find different behaviour due to MIUI framework. in any case, having a bootable ROM is better rather than Non-Bootable with good battery ;)

Comment: Or can I use Simply the stock rom?

Comment: yes you can use stock rom as base as well. Remember there will be no complete step by step guide which will help you to port. In the end, you will only learn after messing with it. All the best for porting :)